# How to have a text-only view of a WordPress website in addition to the fully themed view?

Tags: wordpress, text, themes, accessibility

I have a client who is interested in having a text-only view of their website available to visitors with accessibility needs.  This would be in addition to the usual, fully themed view.

I like what the Kennedy Center did for text-only view, www.kennedy-center.org/text.  I like how it appears to the user as a subdirectory, but I am trying to figure out how to accomplish that in WordPress.  Two themes?  Subdirectory?  Session cookie?  Intercepting the URL and loading different stylesheets?

Any suggestions or any built-in capability that anyone can suggest?

Thanks...

...Allen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very fast way to go is to set a cookie and a GET variable.

Basic example:

In function.php:

```
if (isset($_GET['text'])) { 
    setcookie("is_text", 'true', time()+60*60*24*365*10,"/");
}
```

In header.php:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['is_text'])||isset($_GET['text'])) {
 // text CSS stylesheet
} else {
 // standard CSS stylesheet
}
```

So you can switch the view in every page just by adding `?text` to your url.

Comment: Thanks!  A cookie it is then.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Theme Switcher](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nkthemeswitch/) plugin. 
See here for the demo: http://www.nkuttler.de/wordpress-plugin/theme-switch-and-preview-plugin/